# Transform text-date in format

Tags: excel, date, text, format

I have a text formatted date that looks like this:

```
June 12th 2017, 9:07am PDT
```

How can I transform it in a date format (the classic methods Format Cells and DateValue() don't work)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution uses a helper table listing all the 12 months and their serial number at `A1:B12`

```
January     1
February    2
March       3
April       4
May         5
June        6
July        7
August      8
September   9
October    10
November   11
December   12
```

Assuming the value is in `D10`

Getting the separate elements

Month:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(D10,FIND(" ",D10)-1),A1:B12,2,FALSE)
```

Date:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(" ",D10)+2),2)),RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(" ",D10)+1),1))
```

Year:

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(",",D10)-1),4)
```

Hour:

```
=IF(RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(":",D10)+4),2)="am",RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(":",D10)-1),2),RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(":",D10)-1),2)+12)
```

Minute:

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(":",D10)+2),2)
```

All this combined in the `DATE` and `TIME` function to give a single formula:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(",",D10)-1),4),VLOOKUP(LEFT(D10,FIND(" ",D10)-1),A1:B12,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(" ",D10)+2),2)),RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(" ",D10)+1),1)))+TIME(IF(RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(":",D10)+4),2)="am",RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(":",D10)-1),2),RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(":",D10)-1),2)+12),RIGHT(LEFT(D10,FIND(":",D10)+2),2),0)
```

Then change the format of the cell to:

```
mmmm dd yyyy hh:mm AM/PM "PDT"
```

This will give:

```
June 12 2017 09:07 AM PDT
```

[image]

To add a comma(,), use the custom format:

```
mmmm dd yyyy"," hh:mm AM/PM "PDT"
```

Comment: This great Nitesh! Thank you so much! However, I don't understand why for certain dates it doesn't work (e.g. "June 8th 2017, 9:18am PDT"). Any idea? Thank you again!

Comment: That's because it was returning `8t` as day. I have updated formula to check for 1 digit days. @Mic

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm very sorry though because now the hour and minutes don't work: it only gives 12:00 AM. But the function TIME that you wrote works by itself. It doesn't work when used altogether with DATE. That is whether I keep or not the "+TIME" in your formula doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Mic My bad, missed a bracket just before the `+TIME`. Check now.

Comment: It works!! thank you so much!! I wouldn't have been able to solve this!